# KeyError for JSON data that contains key

Tags: python, json, facebook

I'm working on an app in Flask and want to incorporate Facebook profile pictures for users. Since I have the users' Facebook IDs, I found a really easy way to access the photos through Facebook Graph, which returns JSON data at this URL:

```
img_url = 'http://graph.facebook.com/%s/picture?width=%d&height=%d&redirect=false' \
            % (fb_id, width, height)
```

Here's the JSON data that img_url should return:

```
{
   "data": {
      "height": 200,
      "is_silhouette": false,
      "url": "JPG_URL_HERE",
      "width": 200
   }
}
```

For the specific image URL, I'm using Requests to get a Python dictionary with unicode objects.

```
r = requests.get(img_url).json()
return r['data']['url'].encode('utf-8')
```

All of it works fine in the Python interpreter and returns a string with the image URL. When I run the app with the code in Vagrant, though, I get a KeyError for 'data'. Any thoughts on what's going wrong?

```
  File "/vagrant/app/templates/user/profile.html", line 1, in top-level template code
    {% extends "base.html" %}
  File "/vagrant/app/templates/base.html", line 38, in top-level template code
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
  File "/vagrant/app/templates/user/profile.html", line 9, in block "content"
    <p><img src="{{ current_user.picture(200, 200) }}"></p><br>
  File "/vagrant/app/models.py", line 52, in picture
    return r['data']['url'].encode('utf-8')
  KeyError: 'data'
```

Comment: So what was returned instead then? What *does* `r` contain in that case? Just because it *should* contain a `data` key clearly doesn't mean that it will.

Comment: I'm using the same `img_url` in both cases, so `r` should contain the same data! When I tested in the Python interpreter, the JSON data I listed above is exactly what `r` contains, with the `data` key (including the correct URL).

Comment: Sure, but it is *not there now*. What is there instead?

Comment: Okay, not sure if it's the correct way to check, but when I try to print `r` while the app is running on Vagrant, I get the same KeyError with this additional line: `{"error":{"message":"Unknown path components: \/jackiehluo\/picture","type":"OAuthException","code":2500}}`. Is it possible that I need an access token from Facebook, even though no account access is required?

Comment: Yes, you'll need a token, because even for read access you'll still be tracked for rate limiting purposes.

Answer (score 0):

In your codes:

```
    r = requests.get(img_url).json()`
```

I think the `r` may be result in type `str`, so you should translate it into dict like this:

```
    import json
    r = requests.get(img_url).json()
    r_dict = json.loads(r)
    return r_dict['data']['url'].encode('utf-8')
```

try it.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work and results in a TypeError for `json.loads(r)`. The built-in JSON decoder in Requests should return type `unicode`!

Comment: No, `r` is **not** a JSON string, the `response.json()` method decodes and returns the JSON response. There is no need to use `json.loads()` *again*. See the [*JSON Response Content* section](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#json-response-content) of the quickstart documentation.